# How to use reduce method within map method to add numbers

Tags: javascript, reduce, array.prototype.map

Not sure if I am overcomplicating things but I am trying to get the sum of all the numbers inside this array of arrays:

```
const frames = [
  [2, 0], [4, 2], [6, 0], [2, 4], [1, 5], [7, 0], [5, 2], [7, 0], [2, 6], [8, 1]
]
```

I am practising using `map` and `reduce` to do so:

```
const score = (frames) =>{
  console.log(frames)
  let addedScores = frames.map(frame.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue))
  console.log(addedScores)
}
```

But currently getting this error:

```
TypeError: 2,04,26,02,41,57,05,27,02,68,1 is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at score (/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/devacademy/bootcamp/week1/preparation/bowling-kata/game.js:8:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/devacademy/bootcamp/week1/preparation/bowling-kata/game.js:17:1)
```

[Here is a fiddle version.](https://jsfiddle.net/4gvn63ka/)

Any advice and explanation would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The expression inside the map does not result in a function which `map` expects

Comment: And map returns an array; while you’re trying to reduce the outer and inner arrays to a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there on this one! If you look at the stack trace for the error you are facing, you will see that an error is thrown by `Array.map` function, and namely that "stuff" (i.e `2,04,26,02,41,57,05,27,02,68,1`) is "not a function".

The `map` higher-order function expects a function that it will map accross the elements of `frames`.

What you want is something like this:

```js
//...
  let addedScores = frames.map((frame) => frame.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue))
//...
```

Here I have only converted your `addedScores` expression to pass an anonymous function: `(frame) => { ... }` to the `map` function.

Hope this helps!

The resulting shape for `addedScores` would be: `[2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, ...]`, which is the sum of each pair of numbers in `frames`.